# IIS 7.5 working only from localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

Windows server 2008 R2. Firewall disabled.
IIS allowed connections only from localhost, but not from local network or by this server IP locally. Only localhost or 127.0.0.1
In bindings settings IP addresses not assigned.
IIS fresh installation without any restrictions.
telnet on 80 port also not working
Any reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in wrong bindings (the http.sys don't read correct settings from conf file)
The right answer is:
from command line:
**netsh http show ip listen**

**delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1**

**exit**

and then
restart IIS to apply these changes:
**iisreset**

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your configuration in: IIS -> -> "Web sites" -> your_site > right click -> "Properties" -> "Directory security" tab -> "Edit" in "IP address and domain name restrictions".

If you have chosen "Denied access" change to "Granted access".

Comment: Thanks, but not restrictions in this options. All permissions on directory granted.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it turns out was due to a missing gateway in the network adapter IPv4 settings for the IP address tied to the website.  (Our server had 2 IP addresses, and the default gateway was set for the backup IP, but Windows had at some point made the primary one be blank -- presumably for the reason that in certain cases 2 IPs each having a gateway can cause a conflict if they aren't on the same network...After clicking "ok" to the warning message about this potential conflict, the server accepted the gateway IP address to be added back, and everything worked after that.)

Comment: i am unsure if that is related in case, that it was already solved but nice to know theres a other work around for the same issue